# Why does my sds011 sensor not send the right byte?

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi, sensors

I try to measure air quality with an sds011 connected to a raspberry Pi. Therefore I use a script I found here: https://forum-raspberrypi.de/forum/thread/32634-nova-pm2-5-pm10-feinstaub-sensor-sds011-am-pi-anschlie%C3%9Fen/

I changed it to python3 (`ser.write(b.encode())` instead of `ser.write(b)`).

The script itself is running, but I guess

```
def sensor_read():
    byte = 0
    while byte != "\xaa":
        byte = ser.read(size=1)
    d = ser.read(size=10)
    if d[0] == "\xc0":
        process_frame(byte + d)
```

creates an infinite loop because "byte" never seems to become "\xaa".

Do I just have to wait even longer (about several minutes) or is something wrong with the code?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Why do you expect that `ser.read` will return `"\xaa"` eventually? Have you checked what it returns instead?

Comment: I use a method to "wake up" the sensor by sending bytes to it (ser.write()). The first byte should be "\xaa".    In fact it returns "\x" and two numbers or "\xab" but never "\xaa".

Comment: Then you need to refer to the datasheet of the sensor to figure out why it sends these bytes and what you need to do so that it sends the bytes you expect.